# Node: How Can I Import Web3 To Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, import

I'm trying to import the web3 library in Node.js so that I can handle Ethereum smart contract events, however I can't get the import to work.

I'm running Babel on each file to convert to es5, and the import in Node's index.js file looks like this:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
```

When I add that "import Web3 from 'web3'" statement I get this error:

```
webpack:///./node_modules/scrypt/index.js?:3
var scryptNative = __webpack_require__(!(function 
webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module 
'./build/Release/scrypt'"); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; } . 
()))

^

Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/scrypt'
at webpackMissingModule 
(webpack:///./node_modules/scrypt/index.js?:3:84)
at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/scrypt/index.js?:3:181)
at Object../node_modules/scrypt/index.js
```

This is my version of web3: (However, I have tried other versions which also don't work)

```
"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.26"
```

Does anyone know how I can import the web3 library to Node? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you missing some quotes? `import Web3 from 'web3';`

Comment: Yeah, you're right, not sure how I missed that. I've added the quotes but now I'm getting the "scrypt" error shown above.

Comment: I'd start by searching for that error message. There are a lot of references to it.

Answer (score 1):

Name of the module should be quoted

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
```

Comment: Now seems that the npm dependencies doesn't install correctly. If you'll add a `npm install` log this may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the require for this module:

```
const web3 = require('web3');
```

Comment: Yeah, I'd already tried that syntax with no luck. I am running babel over all of my files and the other "import" statements work fine.

Answer (score 0):

After install web3 using npm install web3, you can import the web3 module using the following line inside your .js file

```
var web3 = require('web3');
```